# Using scheduler where time is stored in list and input for function is also stored in a list

Tags: python, list, time, scheduler

I have the following two lists:

```
marketId_list = ['1.170349308', '1.170349312', '1.170349315']

execution_time_list = ['16:12', '16:13', '16:14']
```

I would like to pass to values from `marketId_list` to a function at the times specified in `execution_time_list`.

For the question, I have the specified the function as such as:

```
def test(market_identification):
    print(market_identification)
```

So at `16:12` `1.170349308` will be printed, at `16:13` `1.170349312` will be printed and at `16:14` `1.170349315` will be printed.

To do this I have written the following code:

```
import schedule
import time

for time_of_execution in execution_time_list:

    for market_identification in marketId_list: 

        schedule.every().tuesday.at(time_of_execution).do(test)
        while True:

            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

Though this gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'market_identification'
```

Comment: In this line you should be passing the argument that you are iterating in your for loop `market_identification`.  `schedule.every().tuesday.at(time_of_execution).do(test(market_identification))`

Comment: When I change `schedule.every().tuesday.at(time_of_execution).do(test)` to `schedule.every().tuesday.at(time_of_execution).do(test(market_identification))` I get the following error `TypeError: the first argument must be callable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the missing argument. One way is to use a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), implemented by a nested function.

Here, the call `test_wrapper(market_identification)` creates a new function that already has the needed argument inside. It is this generated function that will then be called by the schedule framework.

```py
def test(market_identification):
    print(f"test {market_identification}")


def test_wrapper(mi):
    def inner():
        return test(mi)
    return inner


for time_of_execution, market_identification in zip(execution_time_list, marketId_list):
    schedule.every().tuesday.at(time_of_execution).do(test_wrapper(market_identification))
    print(f"scheduled {market_identification} at {time_of_execution}")


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

For a simple demonstration, you can immediately call the generated function:
`test_wrapper("hello")()` 
results in the output

```
test hello
```

Because this use-case for nested function is so common, with the `functools.partial` method the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) provides you a little helper for this:

```py
from functools import partial

for time_of_execution, market_identification in zip(execution_time_list, marketId_list):
    schedule.every().tuesday.at(time_of_execution).do(partial(test, market_identification))
    print(f"scheduled {market_identification} at {time_of_execution}")
```

Please note that the `while` loop must not reside in the inner loop. It has to be executed after all schedulers have been set. I assume the indentation was messed up in the original code. It is fixed in my above answer.

*Update:*
I first overlooked the part where you explain that at every time only one market id is to be used. In that case you do not need two nested loops but a single loop that `zip`s the `execution_time_list` and the `marketId_list`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I would also suggest the use of [partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), which is more general.

Comment: @JoseA. I would say it is more specific and less general :) But you are right, I will include this in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I run the supplied code it returns prints all values of the `marketId_list `  at the first time in `execution_time_list `. What I was looking is that at the first time indicated in `execution_time_list ` that the first value in `marketId_list ` be printed then at the second time indicated `execution_time_list ` that the second value in `marketId_list ` be printed and so forth.

Comment: @sandycaskie yes, sorry for that. I overlooked that part in your question. The answer has been updated to fix that by using the zip method.